# Exception occurs when using OneWay Data Binding in a `WinAppSDK` Desktop Application with `C++/WinRT`

Tags: data-binding, window, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I've got no idea about how to use OneWay Data Binding in my `C++/WinRT` `Windows App SDK` desktop project, since there's not an official guidance nor a demo project.

Every time after I run my App, it always crashes with an exception:

```
The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.
```

And there's a line of warning in output window:

```
XamlCompiler warning WMC1506: OneWay bindings require at least one of their steps to support raising notifications when their value changes.
```

*I've noticed that many `WinUI in Desktop` projects with `C++/WinRT` several years ago is far different from today's project, so I couldn't really learn from their experience.*

At first I followed the `UWP` document of [Data Binding with `C++/WinRT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property), but to find it not working for my `WinAppSDK` project.

I've found a familiar answer about an `UWP/WinUI3` project under Github issues:

> In your output window for Build, did you see a line saying XamlCompiler warning WMC1506: OneWay bindings require at least one of their steps to support raising notifications when their value changes? Did you forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

However, I've implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in my project like this:

```
// Message.idl
namespace XXX
{
    runtimeclass Message : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Message(String content);
        String Content;
    }
}
```

```cpp
// Message.cpp
void Message::Content(hstring const& value)
{
    if (m_content != value) {
        m_content = value;
        m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Content" });
    }
}
```

```xml
<!---MainWindow.XAML--->
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxProducer" 
    Text="{x:Bind MainViewModel.MessageProducer.Content, Mode=OneWay}" .../>
```

Whenever I want to change the text of `TextBox` in runtime like this:

```cpp
MainViewModel().MessageProducer().Content(L"Start Produing...");
```

yet it doesn't work.
The text of `TextBox` won't change, but an exception would occur to make the app crash.

Comment: But do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your MessageProducer class?

Comment: Yes, I've looked into the code of  `Message` class (on which the object `MessageProducer` is created), the `Message` class was automatically generated by Visual Studio like this: `struct Message: MessageT<Message>`. And in the template `MessageT`, it inherited the ` INotifyPropertyChanged` as `struct __declspec(empty_bases) Message_base : implements<D, XXX::Message, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::INotifyPropertyChanged, I...>`

Answer (score 0):

## I just get over the above warning line

The reason why it reported a warning is that **I'm using the constructors to create objects instead of using `winrt::make`**.

*The code organization of `Windows App SDK` is slicely different from the one of `UWP`. In my practice, I make a little changes so that my project could work. At that time, I didn't realize the meaning of using `winrt::make`.*

*By chance I forget to include some libraries that leads to a compiling error, so I replaced the part of `winrt::make` with constructors.*

`ChatGPT` has clarified that in a `Windows App SDK/WinUI3` App, the UI part is working at a different thread from the backend services. And `make` has the in-built function for automatic adjustment of objects between threads.

## Unhandled exception

After recovering with `winrt::make`, the App still crashes whenever I want to change the bound data with the following exception:

```
The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.
```

Comment: In terms of the error, have a look at [Threading functionality migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/guides/threading).